Did Pelé receive 7 physical Ballon d'Or?
To coincide with the 60th anniversary of the Ballon d'Or in 2016, France Football published an internationalized reevaluation of the awards presented before 1995, when only European players were eligible to win the award.
After this, a France Football magazine cover featured Pelé with 7 Ballon d'Or in his possession:

Now this is tricky for 2 things. Firstly, it could have been digitally edited; and secondly, in some ways they look just like Ballon d'Or, and in others they don't, because the original in many photos looks more orangish:

Also, it is hard to imagine that France Football ordered 7 Ballon d'Or made of gold to give for a magazine cover; they make one per year to give away in a globally-broadcast ceremony, and they aren't cheap. So maybe they gave him 7 imitation Ballon d'Or for the photoshoot, that weren't made of real gold?
They actually gave Pelé a 100% real Ballon d'Or once, to honor his career, but only 1, not 7. Was the 7 Ballon d'Or photo digitally created or made with fake Ballon d'Or?
Did Pelé receive 7 physical Ballon d'Or?

To the editor, are you sure you can add the images to the question? I mean, for copyright issues

I believe it's classified as fair use - copyrighted images are included in questions and answers all the time across the network and I've never seen any legal issues arise from it.

The France Football cover is very clearly photoshopped: they appear to have taken a stock image of a Ballon d'Or, photoshopped one into his hand, and photoshopped the other six in front of him.

There are very obvious jagged artefacts around all seven Ballon d'Or, particularly around the top-left, where they were cut out of whatever backdrop they were originally photographed against. There are similar artefacts around Pelé's head.
All seven Ballon d'Or have the exact same lighting, when they should logically be casting shadows on one another.
All seven Ballon d'Or have the exact same perspective, when they should logically appear to be at slightly different angles from the camera.
Pelé is holding the Ballon d'Or in a physically-improbable way, grasping it from the side rather than the base (compare how Cristiano Ronaldo holds his Ballon d'Or in the second image). A Ballon d'Or weighs 7kg, and I find it hard to believe that Pelé - then aged 75 - would have had the grip strength to hold something so large and heavy in such an awkward manner. He doesn't appear to be pressing it against his body, either, as his jacket shows no sign of being ruffled by the Ballon d'Or pressing against it.

The 2016 re-evaluation was unofficial - the original winners remain the true winners - and I can find no evidence suggesting that Pelé (or any of the other alternative winners) were awarded physical Ballon d'Or as part of it.
As for the difference in colour between the Ballon d'Or on the magazine cover and the Ballon d'Or at the awards ceremonies, I think that can be explained by a difference in lighting - awards ceremonies tend to be dimly-lit for dramatic purposes, save for a few spotlights, whereas the Ballon d'Or on the cover was probably shot in a brightly-lit studio and therefore appears much lighter in colour.

Pelé would have never been able to receive the Ballon d'Or, as it was originally intended for european players playing in europe. From the Wikipedia page for the Ballon d'Or:

Originally, it was awarded only to players from Europe and was widely known as the European Footballer of the Year award. In 1995, the Ballon d'Or was expanded to include all players of any origin that have been active at European clubs. The award became a global prize in 2007 with all professional footballers from around the world being eligible; additionally, coaches and captains of national teams were also given the right to vote, before reverting to just journalists in 2016.

The "photo montage" (because it's one) shows what could have been were Pelé a European player, or playing in Europe during his finest years. That's the message conveyed by FF: 7 hypothetical awards...
